# Help building a regular expression in python using the re module

Tags: python, regex, parsing

im writing a simple propositional logic formula parser in python which uses regular expressions re module and the lex/yacc module for lexing/parsing. Originally my code could pick out implication as ->, but adding logical equivalence (<->) caused issues with the compiled expressions

```
IMPLICATION = re.compile('[\s]*\-\>[\s]*')
EQUIVALENCE = re.compile('[\s]*\<\-\>[\s]*')
...
elif self.IMPLICATION.search(formula[0].strip()):
...
elif self.EQUIVALENCE.search(formula[0].strip()):
...
```

I originally tried adding [^<] to the front of -> to make it ignore instances of equivalence but this just made it not accept any instances of implication at all. Any possible help would be warmly welcome :)

Comment: Why are you doing this with regexes and not in the yacc grammar?

Comment: could you post the smallest self-contained example that exhibits this behavior? It may be instructive for you to create this example as well.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, your regular expressions are equivalent to the following:

```
# This is bad, because IMPLICATION also will match every
# string that EQUIVALENCE matches
IMPLICATION = re.compile("->")
EQUIVALENCE = re.compile("<->")
```

As you've written it, you're also matching for *zero or more* whitespace characters before the `->` and `<->` literal. But you're not capturing the spaces, so it's useless to specify "match whether spaces are present or not".  Also, note that `-` and `>` do not need to be escaped in these regular expressions.

You have two options as I see it.  The first is to make sure that `IMPLICATION` does not match the same strings as `EQUIVALENCE`

```
# This ought to work just fine.
IMPLICATION = re.compile("[^<]->")
EQUIVALENCE = re.compile("<->")
```

Another option is to use the [maximal munch method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch); i.e., match against all regular expressions, and choose the longest match.  This would resolve ambiguity by giving EQUIVALENCE a higher precedence than IMPLICATION.

Comment: +1 for cutting down on the cruft. since the op uses elif, though, simply reversing the order of the two tests should do the same trick (although implicitly, not explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this simply by reordering your checking to match equivalences first, and then implications. However, this seems to work :

```
>>> IMPLICATION = re.compile(r'\s*[^\<]\-\>\s*')
>>> EQUIVALENCE = re.compile(r'\s*\<\-\>\s*')
```